# iframe inside WKWebView issues

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have WKWebView where I load html content with loadHTMLString method. In my html code I have two iframes:

```
<iframe align=\"middle\"
 allowtransparency=\"\"
 frameborder=\"0\"
 height=\"820px\"
 id=\"\"
 scrolling=\"no\"
 seamless=\"\"
 src=\"//my.site.ru/files_static/edd/2016/speech_countries/6/first.html\" 
 width=\"100%\">
</iframe>
<iframe align=\"middle\"
 allowtransparency=\"\"
 frameborder=\"0\"
 height=\"820px\"
 id=\"\"
 scrolling=\"no\"
 seamless=\"\"
 src=\"http://my.sample.ru/files_static/edd/2016/speech_countries/6/first.html\" 
 width=\"100%\">
</iframe>
```

Then I call loadHTMLString(myHtmlString, baseURL: URL(string: "https://example.ru")) and have following situation: 
1) first iframe loaded successfully
2) second iframe is empty

If I use http://example.ru as a base url then both iframes loads successfully. But I still can't get why I can't use https protocol in my base url

Comment: Are you sure you're getting those results? You are mixing `my.site.ru` with `my.sample.ru` and `example.ru`. **And** you're setting `src="//my.site.ru/...`? That shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Yep, this is how base url works